# error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'Array' [-Wvla]

Tags: c++, array, punteros

**Me pidieron hacer este ejercicio con ARREGLOS DINAMICOS**:

> Hallar el maximo elemento del arreglo

Lo Realice de la forma tradicional y con punteros usando arreglos estaticos y me funciona bien.
Estoy tratando de implementar ahora con arreglos dinamicos, y me saltan errores, llevo varios dias y no consigo darle con el resultado esperado

```
using namespace std;
/*Hallar el maximo elemento del arreglo.*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int Cantidad=0, Mayor=0;
    int Array[Cantidad],*PunteroArray;
    cout<<"Cantidad: ";
    cin>>Cantidad;
    PunteroArray=new int [Cantidad];
    for(int i=0;i<Cantidad;i++){
        cout<<"Numero["<<i<<"]: ";
        cin>>PunteroArray[i];
        
    }
    cout<<"El Mayor elemento es: "<<Mayor<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### El programa que presentas no cambia el valor de `mayor`

Por lo tanto vale cero todo el tiempo.

Te falta introducir en el bucle `for` algo así como:

```
if ((PunteroArray[i]) > mayor) mayor = PunteroArray[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Los [arreglos de tamaño variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) (VLA) son arreglos cuyo tamaño no es una constante. [No son parte del estándar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/13419694) así que depende del compilador implementarlo o no.

El problema está en esta línea:

```
int Array[Cantidad], *PunteroArray;
```

Justamente estás declarando un arreglo de tamaño `Cantidad`, que es una variable. En realidad no estás usando `Array` por lo que lo más simple es eliminarla y listo. La línea te quedaría así:

```
int *PunteroArray;
```